# how to retrieve the ip of openshift private docker registry when started through minishift and accessed from machine where minishift is present

Tags: openshift, minishift

I have installed openshift through minishift on mac. I am able to run the command `docker login -u developer -p <pass> 172.30.1.1:5000` from the shell where openshift is running. However I need to run the same login command from host mac machine and don't know the ip to use.

The openshift console can be accessed from `https://192.168.64.3:8443`.

The command `minishift openshift registry` returns an error.

I can run the oc commands from mac host machine.

Comment: for anyone who comes with the same question, dont worry even  if the above command gives an error. just login to your minishift vm and find the location of registry service from  there or from OKD ui(build section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you better login to docker daemon: https://docs.okd.io/latest/minishift/using/docker-daemon.html instead that login to the internal registry directly. Once you've done you can use `docker` client as it is bound to your minishift environment.

Comment: yup. got it. was able to connect to daemon and push the images